# Why i get build error when i try to open my android studio project?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm working on my project on Ubuntu, and I decided to move to another computer, so I exported my Android Studio project and opened it in windows. But when gradle build i get error:

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not create task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'.
Cannot query the value of this provider because it has no value available.
```

Is this error caused by different versions of AndroidStudio? how to handle it?

Comment: Update gradle and synch project again, clean your project, close your AS and try again

Comment: Might be, use the same version of `AndroidStudio` in both machines . Moving to lower version of `AndroidStudio` can cause failure because of gradle plugin support.

Comment: But i move to higher version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i change my SDK in Tool>SDK Manager to the lower version because my old project in that version of sdk, and i run the project again. After that all set up.